# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

The dawn of a new year, 2015, now approaches, or has already approached, either way it means that it is now time to reset our Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool Science Fiction or Fantasy events/conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/5326).

Comment: For reference, 2014 ads are [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3239/community-promotion-ads-2014).

Answer (score 26):

[image: The world you made]

Comment: It might be worth splitting the last line into two lines: _Worldbuilding_ and _Stack Exchange_. `.se` is the top-level domain for Sweden, and `worldbuilding.se` is an unregistered domain (though, just watch it get picked up after I mention it).

Answer (score 23):

[image: Movies & TV StackExchange]

Answer (score 20):

[image: Meet the Real Thor -- Join the Mythology Stack Exchange]

Comment: From [here](http://meta.mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/157/community-promotion-ads/193#193).

Answer (score 18):

[image: Space Exploration Stack Exchange]

Comment: From [2014 thread](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/3248/12950)

Comment: What? No "final frontier"?

Answer (score 16):

[image: Need more Potter? Visit J.K. Rowling's Pottermore.com for fresh Potter facts and fun! Updated regularly.]

Comment: This ad was put together by SFF users **Slytherincess** (background image), **SQB**  (suggestion of "More Potter? Pottermore), and **Richard** (final image with font). Thank you for your consideration :)

Answer (score 14):

[See all questions with active bounties http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/scifi.stackexchange.com/bounty.png](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured)

Comment: This is an adaption of [Community Promotion Ads - 2015](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/12383).

Comment: How... Wuhh? How does this work?

Comment: @Pureferret: [This](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/998/8380) seems to be the first ad.

Comment: It isn't on the standard image host.

Answer (score 11):

[image: Astronomy Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Writing exercise chat]

Comment: Just wondering why this advertisement has an LCARS border?

Comment: Because this is the scifi site, so know your audience. Also, LCARS is retro-awesome personified.

Comment: fair point.  I didn't realise this was an ad targeted for SFF!

Answer (score 7):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Visit Health Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Join Law SE. Ask awesome questions]

Answer (score -1):

[image: Transcendence: Journey to the Core (PC, rogue-like/RPG game)]

Comment: This is an ad to the Steam Greenlight page of a game that I absolutely love. Its already playable, and has been for years. I don't know if a "no text" ad will be compelling!

Comment: Text added to ad.

Comment: I'm not voting for this ad because it gives no indication of what it's for. Suggestion: indicate (at least in the mouseover text) that it's a game, and what genre and platform.

Comment: @Gilles Done as suggested.

Answer (score -3):

[image: Our mission is to provide genre news to the community on a regular basis.]

Answer (score -3):

[image: Support this proposal]

Comment: Um, you might be a year too late with your update. ;-)