# Is it okay for me to make a community promotion ad for a game I really like? (no mention of game in post)

Tags: discussion, advertising

It is a science fiction game that has been playable (and continually developed) for years, and its very enjoyable. Not many people know about it. It recently went onto Steam Greenlight, so I'd like to draw more attention to it. Would it be alright to make a [community promotion ad](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5326/community-promotion-ads-2015) for such a thing?

Comment: I think it is fine, as long as you aren't trying to personally profit from this ad.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's pretty much the point of the Community Promotion ads. They're to give SE users a chance to advertise things that this community might be interested in.  The voting threshold on the ads helps filter out stuff that people aren't interested in, or subpar ads.

I say go for it.

Comment: Sweet. I am also worried about if people actually regularly check out the community promotion ads page? Can I somehow draw attention the fact that I just made a new ad?

Comment: @user89 - Mentioning it in the Mos Eisley chatroom will garner a certain amount of attention.