# Mythology SE needs more commitments

Tags: discussion

As many of you probably know, mythology has no home anywhere on the Stack Exchange network. Here on Science Fiction & Fantasy, [some mythology questions are permissible](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5014/22427), but I think we can all agree that this isn't its home.

But there is an **[Area51 proposal for a mythology SE site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58307/mythology?referrer=u4bI8H2eeMTa1Ktl-HOLsw2)**, in the "commitment" stage, which means it needs more people to hit commit, to say that they will be active on the site beta. To that end,  I also promoted the site [on history's meta](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2094/3383).

**Would you like to commit?**

Comment: This is **Off-Topic** because: `This question does not appear to be about Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network within the scope defined in the help center.`

Answer (score 6):

If you want free advertising,  try drawing up a [community ad](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5326/23386), or posting in chat.  But please keep it respectful,  and not too spammy.

Comment: Well, I did [ask in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20368430#20368430) if anyone would object to me posting this in meta. Two people said they wouldn't mind and nobody else said anything, so I took that as a go-ahead. My similar post on History's meta was also well-received.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude I thought you were actually talking about a [Community Promotion Ad](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5326/23386). That would be the proper way, I guess.

Comment: I was one of the people who said that this seemed like a reasonable place to promote it, so I'll freely take some of the blame.

Comment: @SeanDuggan - I was run off of chat so I wasn't one of those people... but I'm fully with you on this. IMHO this is a perfectly acceptable topic on SFF Meta, and I'm voting to reopen and upvoting it.